# JSON lookup table

Tags: javascript, json

I need some help with this JavaScript function. You can see in the first picture that I have a payload with an: ID, timestamp and value. But I want to change only the ID to a better name than "104". In the second picture you see the payload that I want.

[image: Photo] ===> [image: Photo]

To change from "104" to "Battery_Current" I have to use a JSON payload where I can find the corresponding name to the number.

[image: Json array with data]

What does the code need to do: The payload comes in and stores the ID ("104") then it looks up in the TMPmetaTable where ID "104" is and then it gives me the corresponding name? After it found the name the program replaces the current ID "104" with the new "Battery_Current".

```js
var TMPmetaTable = 
    {"Metadata":
    {"0":{"name":"drive0_CurrentRPM","id":"101"},
    "1":{"name":"drive1_CurrentRPM","id":"102"},
    "2":{"name":"Battery_Voltage","id":"103"},
    "3":{"name":"Battery_Current","id":"104"}}
    };


var dataId = msg.payload.id;
var val = TMPmetaTable.Metadata.indexOf(dataID);


msg.payload.id = TMPmetaTable.Metadata[val].name;


console.log(msg)
```

Comment: `var val = TMPmetaTable.Metadata.findIndex(obj => obj.id == dataID);`

Comment: I made you a snippet. Where is msg coming from